# How to plot epochs versus training accuracy in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am working in Keras and would like to produce a plot like Figure 3 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01408.pdf). In the caption of Figure 3 in the paper, its says 10 iterations correspond to 1 epoch. I assume this is due to the batch size used for training per epoch.If anyone has further insights to confirm this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify; your question is quite unclear, and the title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the body of your post

Comment: @desertnaut can you explain what this Figure 3 caption from the paper means: `"Every 10 iterations correspond to a single epoch"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epoch - One pass through the data, or how many times you have seen each record.
Iteration - Update of the models parameters.

Basically they are saying that they updated the model parameters ten times per each pass through the data.

from https://deeplearning4j.org/glossary